# How to check if email already exists excluding the current record mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have created an update route for a product. there are some fields that must be unique.

when creating a product I'm checking that like so

```
const emailExists = await Foodlancer.findOne({ email: values.email });

if (emailExists) {
  return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email already used' });
}
```

But I'm not sure how to check if email is already used when updating a product.

If I use the code above it returns true for the same object that we are updating.

Is there a way to exclude an object? I have looked at `$ne` and `$nin` but not sure how to use them in this case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you could create a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) and enforce this at the database level. this would not let you insert or update an email that exists in the system.

Regarding the logic check you want to do, why not just use the same code for creation on the update with the addition of checking if the `_id` is different with `$ne`

(I'm assuming you're updating with a document `_id` otherwise you would have just used the actual email for the update?)

```
const documentToUpdateId = new ObjectId(req.body._id);
const emailExists = await Foodlancer.findOne({ email: req.body.email, _id: {$ne: documentToUpdateId}});

if (emailExists) {
  return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email already used' });
}
```

Comment: I already have `unique` set to `true` for model

Comment: i am not sure how `mongoose` uniqueness at a model level works, but if it does not create a unique index at the db level (that would also help you're queries) then it does not  guarantee uniqueness, for example it would not cover `$out` or `$merge` output.

Comment: Ok, will look into it.